# An article before soundtrack

Tags: articles

Why the definite article is used before "soundtrack"  but not used before "movie" in the sentence below since both words are unspecified for listener:

> Name a movie where the soundtrack is better than the movie itself.

Answer (score 4):

It's not just any soundtrack.  It's the soundtrack of the movie in question.

That is to say, both words aren't unspecified for the listener.  Only the first instance of "movie" might represent *any* movie.  Once the movie is established, so is its associated soundtrack.

Otherwise, I might answer by saying the soundtrack of *2001: A Space Odyssey* is far better than *Attack of the Killer Tomatoes*.